# Redirecionar stack para pilha ao invés do contrário

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica, tags-sinônimas

A tag [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pilha) é considerada sinônimo da tag [stack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack), de forma que todas as perguntas que recebem a tag [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pilha) são remapeadas para [stack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack).

Entretando, acredito que o que deveria acontecer é o contrário, que as perguntas mapeadas com a tag [stack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack) é que deveriam ser remapeadas para [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pilha).

É possível e desejável realizar-se essa troca?

Comment: Penso eu que `stack` é mais familiar aos usuários do que `pilha`, então por conveniência é usado assim, mesmo que sendo um termo em inglês.

Comment: Eu concordo plenamente com a troca.

Comment: Eu estou com o @Guilherme Nascimento nessa. Sei que é um estrangeirismo mas eu sempre penso em termos de *stacks* ao invés de pilhas (já fazia isso bem antes de mudar para um país que usa Inglês como primeira lingua). É engraçado que o mesmo não acontece com filas / *queues*.